# Remove Coupon Code from invoice

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

I want to remove the coupon code from magento invoice.

[image: how to remove coupon code]

essentially the second row must look like

```
Discount : -Rs374.90
```

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can rewrite the method `_initTotals` from the block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Invoice_Totals` and make it look like this:

```
protected function _initTotals()
{
    $this->getSource()->setDiscountDescription('');
    return parent::_initTotals();
}
```

Comment: Heads off man, awesome solution!